# High rpm at idle

Tags: rpm, mercury, fast-idle, mariner

I changed my spark plugs and ignition coils a few days ago and I’m sure I did everything correctly , but after I put everything back together and started the car the rpm was up around 4000 . Idk if I touched the throttle body cable or something because it is slightly opened and I can’t figure out how to readjust the cables , I’ve watched videos but they don’t look exactly like my cables . I have an 08 mercury mariner

Comment: Hello.  Please tell us which vehicle and engine you have.

Comment: And which engine is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 3.0 L V6 , 08 mercury mariner

Comment: I’m trying to figure out why my rpm is so high at idle when I start my car , idk if I accidentally touched the throttle cables when I was changing my spark plugs .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this car, but perhaps check the Idle Air Control Valve and the vacuum lines and wiring around it. You may have bumped a wire or hose lose or there may be a split in a vacuum line.